# Annotation based api authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have somewhere around 70 of API's of which most of them are secured by following token based approach. There are (let's say 20) open api which do not need any kind of token.

For authentication of secured apis I initially though of implementing it in spring filters and skip this authentication for open api's. Something like below

```
    @Component
    class AccountFilter extends GenericFilterBean {
        @Override
        public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, 
             FilterChain chain) {
             if(request.getRequestURI().contains.(list of open apis)) {
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
                return;
             } else {
                /*
                 * logic for token validation 
                 *
             }
        }
    }
```

But sooner found it becoming tedious. I mean putting if else for 20 apis makes code look cluttered.

Eventually I thought of creating a custom annotation something like @Authenticator and implement the token validation logic there. Put this annotation on RestController methods of secured api's and omit it from open api's.

```
@RentionPolicy
@Target
@interface Authenticator {

}

@RestController
public class TestController {

     @Authenticator
     @GetMapping(/api/v1/securedapi)
     public void testSecurily() {

     }

     // Omit @Authenticator from non secured api
     @GetMapping(/api/v1/api)
     public void test() {

     }

}
```

Unfortunately, I could not find anything which helps me. All I can find is spring security but that is not in my scope as of now.

I know spring supports custom annotations but I could not find anything which fulfils my requirement.

Can any one help me with this?

Also I want to know

1. If my approach is right? If yes how can i proceed further?
2. If not how can I achieve this functionality without cluttering my code.

Comment: Why don't you use an authentication configuration which extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` ?

Comment: These are the legacy api's and they do not follow proper structure. For example **/api/v1/admin** is not secure but **/api/v1/admin/product** is secure. So if I write it in matcher, both would pass in same way.
That is why I wanted a annotation based approach where I can directly put the annotation on the api's which I want to be secured,

Comment: Take a look at example here: https://gist.github.com/thomasdarimont/8d6bc243d3b504439e67d57cb0d0bb72 You can give roles to endpoints so one can require role, other not.